# Объясните что такое XDG? и XDG Base Directory?

Tags: linux, laravel

Как я понимаю это некая настройка для группировки папок по разным назначениям. И какую конкретную роль эта штука переписанная для php играет во  фреймворке Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

аббревиатура *xdg* расшифровывается как *x desktop group*. так раньше называлась инициативная группа по стандартизации различных графических сред пользователя для операционных систем posix. сейчас эта группа называется [freedesktop.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org), но аббревиатура *xdg* продолжает фигурировать в уже выпущенных стандартах, написанной документации и коде.

---

*xdg base directory* — это одна из [выпущенных спецификаций](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/), определяющая, где (в каких каталогах файловой системы) следует искать файлы, связанные с *xdg*.

---

«связаны» могут быть *laravel* и *xdg*, вероятно, через [эту реализацию спецификации на языке *php*](https://github.com/dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir), а
судя по тому, что в [исходных кодах самого фреймворка](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) не встречается упоминаний аббревиатуры *xdg*, упомянутая реализация, возможно, используется в каком-нибудь из [дополнений laravel](https://packalyst.com/), вероятнее всего, для определения [mime](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)-типа файла по его суффиксу/содержимому — ведь эту информацию определяет [ещё одна из xdg-спецификаций](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html), и для извлечения этой информации как раз и требуется вначале получить пути к *базовым каталогам xdg* (*xdg base directory*).